# Database data not displaying on webpage

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to view data of a row in phpmyadmin. 
I have a table of employees in my database. It is a leave management portal. I created a "view" button, so if an admin clicks on it, it should display the details of the employee and the leave requested/taken. But it doesn't seem to work.
 
Below is my code. I'm new to php

```php
<table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered'>

  <td>First Name</td>
  <td>
    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($FirstName, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>
  </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td>
      <?php echo htmlspecialchars($LastName, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Leave Type</td>
    <td>
      <?php echo htmlspecialchars($LeaveType, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>From Date</td>
    <td>
      <?php echo htmlspecialchars($FromDate, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>To Date</td>
    <td>
      <?php echo htmlspecialchars($ToDate, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>
      <?php echo htmlspecialchars($Description, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Admin Remark</td>
    <td>
      <?php echo htmlspecialchars($AdminRemark, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Admin Remark Date</td>
    <td>
      <?php echo htmlspecialchars($AdminRemarkDate, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Status</td>
    <td>
      <?php echo htmlspecialchars($Status, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Read</td>
    <td>
      <?php echo htmlspecialchars($IsRead, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <a href='index.php' class='btn btn-danger'>Back to Leave History</a>
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>


<td>
</td>
</tr>


</tbody>
</table>
<tbody>

  <?php

    $id=isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : die('ERROR: Record ID not found.');

    try {

        $query = "SELECT id, FirstName, LastName, LeaveType, FromDate, ToDate, Description, AdminRemark, AdminRemarkDate, Status, IsRead FROM tblleaves WHERE id = ? LIMIT 0,1";
        $stmt = $con->prepare( $query );
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $FirstName = $row['FirstName
        $LastName = $row['LastName'];
        $LeaveType = $row['LeaveType'];
        $FromDate = $row['FromDate'];
        $ToDate = $row['ToDate'];
          $Description = $row['Description'];
        $AdminRemark = $row['AdminRemark'];
        $AdminRemarkDate = $row['AdminRemarkDate'];
        $Status = $row['Status'];
        $IsRead = $row['IsRead'];   
    }
    catch(PDOException $exception){
        die('ERROR: ' . $exception->getMessage());
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: What kind of error are you getting on the page? Also you have this character ` at the beginning of your file.

Comment: The line `$FirstName = $row['FirstName` is missing at least a `'];`. It probably should look like `$FirstName = $row['FirstName'];`

Comment: It seems you have a lot of errors in your code. Please let me know what is the error message currently.

Comment: html syntax for table is incorrect - you're missing some `tr` tags (there are only closing tags), `tbody` tag is outside `table`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You are querying the results and storing it in variables after your `HTML`. Since variables aren't set, HTML will not have those values and hence it's not printing any values.

Place query results on top and HTML at the bottom.